# Is there a "don't compile" #define in visual studio for .cpp files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Is there a #define/#pragma or something I can add at the beginning of a .cpp file to exclude it from compilation in visual studio? I want to use that for debugging purposes.

Comment: It is hard to imagine how this would be useful for debugging purposes. You'll get just linker errors about undefined symbols.

Comment: @CodyGray well, maybe not so much debugging purposes, I do some online programming contests and I use visual studio, usually there are several tasks (about 5) and each solution is supposed to be written in just one .cpp file, I don't want to remove the file when I'm done with a task, so I was wondering how to just exclude it from the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the file properties in VS and set `Exclude from build` to `yes` under `Configuration properties / General`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of one using `#define` or `#pragma`, but you can always do `#if 0` at the start of the file and `#endif` at the end.

Comment: Yea, that I know.